# how to update using SIGNALS

Tags: python, django, django-signals

models.py

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    objects = None
    room_num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Комната')
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Релевантность')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Категория')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=105,verbose_name='Цена (сум)')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room_num}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комнату'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комнаты'

class Registration(models.Model):
    objects = None
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Номер',help_text='Номер в который хотите заселить гостя!')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Фамилия')
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Администратор')
    pasport_serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Серия паспорта',help_text='*AB-0123456')
    birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата рождения')
    img = models.FileField(verbose_name='Фото документа',help_text='Загружайте файл в формате .pdf')
    visit_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=datetime.datetime.now().hour,
                                  minute=datetime.datetime.now().minute, second=00,),verbose_name='Дата прибытия')
    leave_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day + 1, hour=12, minute=00, second=00),verbose_name='Дата отбытия')
    guest_count = models.IntegerField(default=1,verbose_name='Кол-во людей')
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name='Релевантность',help_text='При бронирование отключите галочку')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=105,default='Появится после сохранения!',verbose_name='Цена (сум)')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rooms},{self.last_name},{self.first_name},{self.room_bool}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Номер'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Регистрация'
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Registration


@receiver(post_save, sender=Registration)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.rooms.room_bool = False
        instance.rooms.save()
```

this is the code in the signals that updates the value from another model according to the value of another WHEN I CREATE (if in model 1 it will be `False`, then in model 2 it will also be `False`) how can I make it so that when EDITING changes the values

Comment: Remove the `if created` check.

Comment: This is however not very efficient: it require two queries, you can likely remove one query. Can you share the relevant models?

Comment: look now i edited

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem gives an error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Registration)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.rooms.room_bool = instance.room_bool
        instance.rooms.save()
        instance.price = instance.rooms.price
        instance.save()
    elif not created:
        instance.rooms.room_bool = instance.room_bool
        instance.rooms.save()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend use pre_save signal for this situation

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Registration)
def create_profile(instance, *args, **kwargs):
    if instance.pk #Its update
 
    else: #Its create
```

django.db.models.signals.[pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#pre-save)

This is sent at the beginning of a model’s save() method.

django.db.models.signals.[post_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#post-save)

Like pre_save but sent at the end of the save() method

your model will not has id when creating so you can catch with pk instance is data for your model

Comment: CAN YOU HELP ME WITH THIS QUESTION https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72404921/how-to-cancel-an-add-django