# How to cancel an add django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a model and there are relevance values. how can I make it so that while one object (101) is false so that it cannot be added, and when the value is true, you can

IN ADMIN PANEL

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    objects = None
    room_num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Комната')
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(default=True,verbose_name='Релевантность')
    category = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Категория')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=105,verbose_name='Цена (сум)')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.room_num}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Комнату'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Комнаты'

class Registration(models.Model):
    objects = None
    rooms = models.ForeignKey(Rooms, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Номер',help_text='Номер в который хотите заселить гостя!')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150,verbose_name='Фамилия')
    admin = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name='Администратор')
    pasport_serial_num = models.CharField(max_length=100,verbose_name='Серия паспорта',help_text='*AB-0123456')
    birth_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата рождения')
    img = models.FileField(verbose_name='Фото документа',help_text='Загружайте файл в формате .pdf')
    visit_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day, hour=datetime.datetime.now().hour,
                                  minute=datetime.datetime.now().minute, second=00,),verbose_name='Дата прибытия')
    leave_date = models.DateTimeField(
        default=datetime.datetime(year=year, month=month, day=day + 1, hour=12, minute=00, second=00),verbose_name='Дата отбытия')
    guest_count = models.IntegerField(default=1,verbose_name='Кол-во людей')
    room_bool = models.BooleanField(default=False,verbose_name='Релевантность',help_text='При бронирование отключите галочку')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=105,default='Появится после сохранения!',verbose_name='Цена (сум)')
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rooms},{self.last_name},{self.first_name},{self.room_bool}'

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Номер'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Регистрация'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`limit_choices_to=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to) to filter the items for the `ForeignKey`, so:

```
class Registration(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(
        Room,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        limit_choices_to={'room_bool': True},
        verbose_name='Номер',
        help_text='Номер в который хотите заселить гостя!'
    )
    # …
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Room` instead of <s>`Rooms`</s>.

Comment: it helped but only half
I can't add new ones if there is a False value but I can't edit existing ones on True

Comment: is it possible to make it look not at Room.room_bool but at Registrations.room_bool

Comment: Could you explain me more what is problem ? which models boolean field, what you exactly want

Comment: @AbduvahobKaxarov when i set limit_choices_to i got what i wanted.
I can't add rooms that are already occupied, but I can't edit old ones either.
You need to edit the room_bool after the client left the room and it was freed and now I can’t do this